# Unit testing F# code without using an existing test library (MSTest, xUnit, etc.)

Tags: unit-testing, f#

I know I can probably use MSTest (I'm under Linux without an IDE so maybe not?) or another unit testing library, but for a small project I decided to write my own unit tests without resorting to a framework (for fun and for learning).

Right now, I have only one type of assert and one test but I would like a code review to improve my code now to make sure I am on the right track.

```
module Tests

// modules under test
open HeightMap
open MidpointDisplacement

// assert functions
let assertAreEqual expected actual =
    printf "... "
    if expected <> actual then printfn "%s" ("Test failed, expected " + expected.ToString() + ", actual " + actual.ToString())  
    else printfn "Test passed"

// tests
let testNewHeightMapReturnZeroInitializedHm () = 
    let hm = newHeightMap 5
    let result = hm.Map |> Array.sum
    assertAreEqual 0.0 result

// tests included in run
let testsToRun = 
    [
        ("test newHeightMap will return a 0 initialized height map",
         testNewHeightMapReturnZeroInitializedHm)
    ]

// test runner
let runSingleTest test = 
    let testName, testFunction = test
    printf "%s" testName    
    testFunction()

let runTests =
    testsToRun |> List.map runSingleTest |> ignore
    printfn "%s" "Ran all tests."
```

One thing that bugs me is that I there is some redundancy by specifying the test function and then including it in a list inside a tuple.

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/mausch/Fuchu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overall this looks ok, just a couple nitpicks:

1. In `assertAreEqual`, you're using string concatenation and then passing the resulting string to formatting function. You could use the formatting function to begin with:

   ```
   if expected <> actual then 
       printfn "Test failed, expected %A, actual %A" expected actual  
   else 
       printfn "Test passed"
   ```
2. Parentheses around tuples are not required, so:

   ```
   let testsToRun = 
   [
       "test newHeightMap will return a 0 initialized height map",
       testNewHeightMapReturnZeroInitializedHm
   ]
   ```
3. Function parameters are actually patterns, so you can destructure the tuple right there, instead of on a separate line:

   ```
   let runSingleTest (testName, testFunction) = 
       ...
   ```
4. As a general rule, if you have to use `ignore`, it means that there is something wrong somewhere. `ignore` is a hack, a way to squeeze a round peg in a square hole. In your particular case, you're mapping over a list solely for the side-effects. To do this, use `List.iter`, which returns `unit`, so no need for `ignore.

   ```
   testsToRun |> List.iter runSingleTest
   ```
5. The pervasive use of side-effecting computations (i.e. `printfn` etc.) sets off my spidey sense: this makes your code inflexible (e.g. what if you want to have different reporting formats - one for console run, one for CI server, etc.).
   You should structure your code in such a way that it doesn't produce side effects as it runs, but instead produces a value that describes the run, and which can later be used (or not used) to produce the effects. For example, in your case, rather than printing out errors, I would return a list of them, and have the consumer decide what to do with that list. Of course, this would mean significant restructuring of your whole program, so I won't give a code example.
6. Finally, "parametrize all the things!" Try to take stuff as parameters as much as possible, rather than relying on stuff existing in the environment. For example, the `runTests` function should really take the list of tests as parameter.
7. As far as the thing that bugs you, there is an easy solution for it: you don't have to name your functions, you can declare them inline as lambda-expressions:

   ```
   let testsToRun = 
       [
           "test newHeightMap will return a 0 initialized height map",
           fun() -> 
               let hm = newHeightMap 5
               let result = hm.Map |> Array.sum
               assertAreEqual 0.0 result
       ]
   ```
8. Or, alternatively, you can give a name to the pair of name+function, and then include that pair in the list:

   ```
   let theTest = "test newHeightMap will return a 0 initialized height map", fun() -> 
       let hm = newHeightMap 5
       let result = hm.Map |> Array.sum
       assertAreEqual 0.0 result

   let testsToRun = [ theTest ]
   ```

Comment: Just added two points about the "thing that bugs you". Didn't notice it at first, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

> One thing that bugs me is that I there is some redundancy by
>   specifying the test function and then including it in a list inside a
>   tuple.

That's a familiar smell. I came across the same thing when I was building a test framework in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba). Fortunately, you've got better tools at your disposal than I did.

This is easiest handled by [creating a custom attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233179.aspx), marking your test methods with it, and then [reflecting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353491.aspx) over the code to generate a list of test methods to be run on the fly. Implementation is left as an exercise for the reader.